# Error 1064 trying to create new trigger

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a mysql trigger on delete to write a record on a history table but everytime I am getting error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 14 


DELIMITER $$

USE `cedecapr_test`$$


    CREATE
    DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
    TRIGGER `mytable`.`users_delete`
    BEFORE DELETE ON `mytable`.`users`
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
         INSERT INTO `history_table_users`                 
         VALUES
         (          

              OLD.`username`
              );

    END$$
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Which line is line 14?

Comment: empty line between ( and OLD.

Comment: Is `mytable` supposed to be your database? I assume the name of the table you're deleting from is `users`, correct?

Comment: Can you provide the structure of the `users` table and the `history_table_users` table? This might help me help you out.

Comment: This trigger definition seems valid. In fact, it works for me, tested in 5.5.17... whitespace is ignored, and there is minimal validation done on the `VALUES()` (e.g. column count is validated at runtime) ... so, why is the formatting so haphazard?  Have you removed something?  Sanitized something out?  The parse error suggests that there's something we can't see.  Also, it seems strange that you're changing to one database (cedecapr_test) and then defining a trigger in a different database (mytable)... you have a database called "mytable"? Have you tried just retyping this?